# Linux: Shell script has 775 permissions but PHP from browser cannot run it

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, nginx

I have a simple shell script, it is entirely:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
```

If I check ownership and permissions it is:

```
-rwxrwxr-x localuser localuser 31 Aug 16 12:00 shell.sh
```

I have a PHP file which is also owned by `localuser` (though I have tried with it owned by `nginx`, too) and has `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions.  The thing is, my server is running as `nginx`.  When I run a simple PHP file called `test.php` which in turn calls `shell.sh` it *works in the command line*, but never in PHP executed by visiting the page in my browser.

I have tried:

- Setting the ownership of `shell.sh` to `nginx`
- In the `test.php` file I have used `chdir()` and relative path to run `shell.sh` as well as absolute path
- I have tried `exec()`, `system()` and `shell_exec()` to run `shell.sh`

I'm sure there is simply some permission issue I do not understand, but I have no clue what it is.

Comment: if you believe it is the code that is failing, then show the relevant code.

Comment: I don't believe it is the code that's failing... I suspect it's a permission issue that I simply don't understand.  As I said, when I run it in the shell window as `php test.php` it works.  No code issues.

Comment: Most likely PHP is running in safe mode, or `exec` and its siblings are disabled in the `php.ini`. There is usually a separate `php.ini` for the cli, so that would explain why it works there. If you have control of the server, you can just turn off safe mode in the `php.ini` and/or remove `exec` from the list of disable functions. If you are on a shared server you will probably need to contact your web host.

Comment: turning off safe mode is of course... unsafe :-) That's why it's there. If you allow external scripts to be called from php and you give those scripts parameters coming from input to a webpage, you are 100% sure to have a code injection on your server.

Comment: @Gunstick No you're not... You just need to properly sanitize everything.

Comment: and we all know that sanitizing is 100% failsafe. Hmm... 'properly' may be the issue.